# TeleBot, проверка на тип файла, как можно реализовать?

Tags: python, telebot

Есть бот в телеграмме, ему юзеры скидывают файл
Пример:
Юзер: скидывает файл
Бот: отвечает

Нужно чтобы бот отвечал ТОЛЬКО на файл типа `.exe`, а на другие файлы не отвечал
Как можно это реализовать?
Использую `telebot`

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def file_message(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    bot.reply_to(message, "test")
 
    time.sleep(10)
 
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, open(r'C:/python/crypto/libertycrypt_bot.exe', 'rb'))
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Получать в хендлере имя файла, делать `split` по точке, и второй элемент в списке будет являться расширением файла, если `exe` какие-то действия, если нет: `pass`

Comment: Не могли-бы вы показать как это выглядит в коде? Мне так будет более понятней @ClarkDevlin

Comment: Покажите свой код

Comment: @ClarkDevlin
https://pastebin.com/ZK7chKmH

Comment: Добавил ответ, попробуйте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так, и на будущее: используйте `aiogram`

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def file_message(message):
    file_name = message.document.file_name.split('.')
    if file_name[1] == 'exe':
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        bot.reply_to(message, "test")
        time.sleep(10)
        bot.send_document(message.chat.id, open(r'C:/python/crypto/libertycrypt_bot.exe', 'rb'))
bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

Comment: Благодарю, хочу сначала разобраться с telebot, а потом уже и aiogram
Ещё раз большое спасибо @Clark Devlin

Comment: @GatsMerin если ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его как правильный.